# Get items from a SharePoint List using REST API

Tags: custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to retrieve items from a SP List based on the Date_of_Event.

I want all items in the list which occurred the last month.

How does my request looks like?

```
var urlForOrderBy = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?" +
    "$select=ID,Title,Country,Date_of_Event,LandCode," + .......
    &$orderby=Date_of_Event desc";
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
var today = new Date();
var lastmonth = today.setMonth(today.getMonth()-1);

var urlForOrderBy = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?" +
 "$select=ID,Title,Country,Date_of_Event,LandCode," + 
 "$filter=Date_of_Event gt " + lastmonth.toISOString() + 
 "&$orderby=Date_of_Event desc";
```

Comment: Mike,
does that use the previous month or really the last 30 days?
for example when it is 30 oct, will it include all events from 1 sep until 30 oct?

Comment: see my edit--changed it to your requirements

Comment: Mike, thanks for the update. I hope I explained myself clearly in English :) because what I wanted is using the date of today and up until max 30 days before that. For example events between 3 oct and 3 nov (today).

Comment: then it was how I had it before. Let me change it back. This is get all events within the last month. So from October 3rd through November 3rd.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear

Comment: that's okay! glad to be of help.

Comment: Mike,

when running the query I get an error message in the console.
; expected at

var urlForAllItems = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?" +
 "$select=Title,Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event,Country0/Title,Country0/Column2&$expand=Country0" + 
 "$filter=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event gt " [; expected here]lastmonth.toISOString() + 
 "&$orderby=Date_of_Event desc";

Comment: forgot a plus fixed

Answer (score 1):

I solved the question.

```
var urlForAllItems = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?" +
"$select=Title,Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event,Country0/Title,Country0/Column2&$expand=Country0&" +
 "$filter=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event gt '"+startDate+"'&$orderby=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event desc";
```